# Translating an encryption method from Java to C#

Tags: java, c#, encryption, aes

I need to implement an encryption and decryption method pair using C# that uses "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding". The original code is in Java. Here is the encryption method in Java:

```
public static String Encrypt(String plainText, byte[] key2) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
      byte[] encryptedTextBytes=null;
      byte[] key3 =null;
      MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
      key3= sha.digest(key2);
      key3 = copyOf(key3, 16);
      SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key3, "AES");
      // Instantiate the cipher
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
      encryptedTextBytes = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
      return new Base64().encode(encryptedTextBytes);
}
```

And this is my attempt at reconstructing it in C#:

```
public static string Encrypt_AES(string plainText, byte[] key2)
{
    var sha = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();            
    byte[] key3 = new byte[16];
    sha.TransformFinalBlock(key2, 0, key2.Length);
    var tmpkey = sha.Hash;
    Array.Copy(tmpkey, key3, 16);

    var aes = new System.Security.Cryptography.AesCryptoServiceProvider();
    aes.Padding = System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    aes.Mode = System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.ECB;
    aes.Key = key3;
    var plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
    var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor();
    byte[] encryptedTextBytes = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedTextBytes);
}
```

After encrypting some content and sending it to a remote service, the service replies with an error saying that it could not decrypt the message. So I'm assuming something is wrong with it.

I also have an example for a decrypt method in Java. I implemented that method too and tried to encrypt and decrypt some text locally. When I do that, the Decrypt_AES method is throwing a `CryptographicException` at TransformFinalBlock() saying "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed." Maybe I'm using the CryptoProvider classes wrong?

Here are the Java and C# versions of the decrypt function:
Java

```
public static String Decrypt(String encryptedText, byte[] key2) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,NoSuchPaddingException,InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] decryptedTextBytes=null;
    byte[] key3 =null;
    MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    key3= sha.digest(key2);
    key3 = copyOf(key3, 16);
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key3, "AES");
    // Instantiate the cipher
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
    byte[] encryptedTextBytes = new Base64().decode(encryptedText);
    decryptedTextBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedTextBytes);
    return new String(decryptedTextBytes);
}
```

C#

```
public static string Decrypt_AES(byte[] key2, string encryptedText)
{
    var sha = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] key3 = new byte[16];
    sha.TransformFinalBlock(key2, 0, key2.Length);
    var tmpkey = sha.Hash;
    Array.Copy(tmpkey, key3, 16);

    var aes = new System.Security.Cryptography.AesCryptoServiceProvider();
    aes.Padding = System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    aes.Mode = System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.ECB;
    aes.Key = key3;

    var encryptedBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptedText);
    var decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor();
    var decryptedBytes = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length);            

    return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedBytes);
}
```

Thank you for any hint in advance!

Comment: You'll need to say what is going wrong. I.e. what did you expect, and what did you observe instead? Otherwise the question is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not Base64-decoding your ciphertext in your decrypt method.

```
var encryptedBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptedText);
```

should be changed to something like

```
var encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);
```

Comment: This makes the decrypt method work correctly, thanks. But there is still something wrong with the encryption method. Any idea on what could be different between the java and the C# encrypt methods?

Comment: I ran the java code and C# code with the same input now. And it produces the exact same output. Seems like my method was correct after all. I will contact the developers of the service I'm trying to call. If there wasn't anything else then I'll accept this answer because it solved the only thing wrong. Thanks again @JamesKPolk